# Items Template code-behind

Tags: c#, xaml, datatemplate

Is there a way to access the containers generated for an itemscontrol's items?

For example,
Given an ItemsControl with an ItemTemplate as shown below, access the actual TextBlock within the DataTemplate generated for each item in the control. (not the object, but its associated textblock).

Views/MainPage.xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="PhoneApp1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PhoneApp1.ViewModels"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.    Toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <phone:Pivot>
        <phone:Pivot.Resources>
            <vm:PersonViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
        </phone:Pivot.Resources>

        <phone:PivotItem>
            <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Pivot"/>
            </phone:PivotItem.Header>

            <ItemsControl x:Name="People" DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}"     ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock toolkit:SlideInEffect.LineIndex="{Binding PersonLineIndex}"     Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <phone:PivotItem>
            <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Empty Pivot"/>
            </phone:PivotItem.Header>
        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Views/MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace PhoneApp1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModels/PersonViewModel.cs

```
using PhoneApp1.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace PhoneApp1.ViewModels
{
    public class PersonViewModel
    {
        public PersonViewModel()
        {
            People = new ObservableCollection<Person>
            {
                new Person { Name = "Joe" },
                new Person { Name = "Jack" },
                new Person { Name = "James" },
                new Person { Name = "John" }
            };

            PersonLineIndex = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < People.Count; i++)
            {
                PersonLineIndex.Add(i);
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }

        public List<int> PersonLineIndex { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Models/Person.cs:

```
namespace PhoneApp1.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Why would I need this access? For example:
Try to set a different line index for each textblock. Without adding a "LineIndex" property to your Person (as that would violate MVVM).

Comment: What do you want that for?

Comment: Hello @HighCore, because I need to change a property in the textblock individually for each person, and I do not want to violate MVVM separation between models and views by simply adding that property to the person and binding it to each textblock.

Comment: That's what a ViewModel is for. Wrap your data items (Model) in a proper ViewModel and use DataBinding to manipulate the UI.

Comment: I don't think you understand the question, here is an example:
Try to set a different, for example, font for each generated textblock. Without adding a "Font" property to your Person, as that would violate MVVM.

Comment: Why is the ProjectViewModel in a resource? Typically you would just set the DataContext.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera in that case, you would bind to a property on the view model that could be converted to a Font and then use a converter.

Comment: @mikez I don't see how that could work.
I tried to make my example very general in hopes that people would help, but I will make it more specific to my problem so you understand the problem.

Comment: @mikez See the new example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You would access such ItemsControl's ItemContainerGenerator

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        People.Loaded += People_Loaded;
    }

    void People_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < People.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var container = People.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            container.SetValue(SlideInEffect.LineIndexProperty, i);
        }
    }
}
```